# How to modify a word in a sentence using regex to find the word in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a sentence with words/equations in it that start and end with $.
For example,

```
"The $girl$ is a $good$ person"
```

I want to modify the sentence to

```
"The $$girl$$ is a $$good$$ person".
```

I have found a way to find the words but how to replace them with the modified version of themselves is the issue.
I found this on this platform but it doesn't answer the question.

```
preg_replace('/\$\S+\$/', '', $text)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```php
$text = 'The $girl$ is a $good$ person';
echo preg_replace('/\$[^\s$]+\$/', '\$$0\$', $text);
// => The $$girl$$ is a $$good$$ person
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/bBE8E). See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d2yQ6x/2). *Details*:

- `\$` - a `$` literal char
- `[^\s$]+` - any one or more chars other than `$` and whitespace
- `\$` - a `$` literal char.

The `\$$0\$` replacement means the whole match is replaced with itself (`$0`) and two `$` are added on both ends.

To avoid re-wrapping `$$...$$` substrings, you can use

```php
$text = 'The $girl$ is a $good$ person, and keep $$this$$.';
echo preg_replace('/\${2,}[^\s$]+\${2,}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\$[^\s$]+\$/', '\$$0\$', $text);
// => The $$girl$$ is a $$good$$ person, and keep $$this$$.
```

See [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/8XLjK). The `\${2,}[^\s$]+\${2,}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|` part matches all substrings not containing `$` and whitespace between two or more `$` chars and skips them.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d2yQ6x/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can assert whitespace boundaries around the pattern and use the full match using `$0` around dollar signs.

Note that `\S` can also match `$` so you could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^$]` to match any character except the `$`

```
(?<!\S)\$[^$]+\$(?!\S)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `\$` Match `$`
- `[^$]+` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except `$`
- `\$` Match `$`
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ax5MhR/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/hEnkpe).

```
$text = '"The $girl$ is a $good$ person"';
echo preg_replace('/(?<!\S)\$[^$]+\$(?!\S)/', '$$0$', $text);
```

Output

```
The $$girl$$ is a $$good$$ person
```